# Shrink equations in align to fit page width

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, width

I read several similar questions, but none was on align environment. Here is my example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent where $B(a, b) := \int_{0}^{1} y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1} dy$. When $\xi<0$, similar calculations induce the same results. Hence, the first and second moments of $X_{i:n}$  corresponding to a GP random variable are as follows.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb EX_{i:n}   &= \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} [B(n-i+1, i)- B(n-i+\xi+1, i)]. \\ 
\mathbb EX_{i:n}^2 &= \left(\frac{\sigma}{\xi}\right)^2\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} [B(n-i+1, i) -2B(n-i+\xi+1, i) + B(n-i+2\xi+1, i)].
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

How do I shrink the second expression so that it is still aligned at the equal sign but with the same width as the text above it, please? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I stacked the last term under the next to last, with 5pt gap between lines, and left alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\stackalignment{l}

\begin{document}

\noindent where $B(a, b) := \int_{0}^{1} y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1} dy$. When $\xi<0$, similar calculations induce the same results. Hence, the first and second moments of $X_{i:n}$  corresponding to a GP random variable are as follows.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb EX_{i:n}   &= \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} 
  [B(n-i+1, i)- B(n-i+\xi+1, i)]. \\ 
\mathbb EX_{i:n}^2 &= \left(\frac{\sigma}{\xi}\right)^2\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} 
  [B(n-i+1, i) \stackunder[5pt]{{}-2B(n-i+\xi+1, i)}{ {}+ B(n-i+2\xi+1, i)].}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Despite admonitions, the OP would like the 2nd equation shrunk to fit.  If one limits the shrink to just the right-hand side of the 2nd equation, it could be done as follows, by placing that part of the equation in `\text{\footnotesize$...$}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent where $B(a, b) := \int_{0}^{1} y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1} dy$. When $\xi<0$, similar calculations induce the same results. Hence, the first and second moments of $X_{i:n}$  corresponding to a GP random variable are as follows.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb EX_{i:n}   &= \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} [B(n-i+1, i)- B(n-i+\xi+1, i)]. \\ 
\mathbb EX_{i:n}^2 &= \text{\footnotesize$\left(\frac{\sigma}{\xi}\right)^2\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} [B(n-i+1, i) -2B(n-i+\xi+1, i) + B(n-i+2\xi+1, i)].$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As another alternative, one could make the whole equation in footnote size, with `{\footnotesize\begin{align}...\end{align}\par}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent where $B(a, b) := \int_{0}^{1} y^{a-1}(1-y)^{b-1} dy$. When $\xi<0$, similar calculations induce the same results. Hence, the first and second moments of $X_{i:n}$  corresponding to a GP random variable are as follows.
{\footnotesize
\begin{align*}
\mathbb EX_{i:n}   &= \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} [B(n-i+1, i)- B(n-i+\xi+1, i)]. \\ 
\mathbb EX_{i:n}^2 &= \left(\frac{\sigma}{\xi}\right)^2\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} [B(n-i+1, i) -2B(n-i+\xi+1, i) + B(n-i+2\xi+1, i)].
\end{align*}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks good. But is it possible to put the second expression in just one line, please?

Comment: @LaTeXfan I understand your request.  I think changing the font size mid-equation would not look good at all.  We'll see if I can muster it...while holding my nose.

Comment: @LaTeXfan Please see revision.

Comment: I know it is a very vague answer but I just put the geometry package and the second expression is still in one line but with a less width as the text