# Shrink equation in align to fit page width without creating new line

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249482/shrink-equations-in-align-to-fit-page-width) post about fitting equations to the page width, but it did not really answer my question. I have the following snippet of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}        
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
I:=&...\\
&=(1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^m(-1)^n)b_{mn}\int_0^\infty\xi_2^n\int_0^\infty\xi_1^m\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1\xi_1^2)\mathrm d\xi_1\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_2\xi_2^2)\mathrm d\xi_2\\
& = (1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^m(-1)^n)I_1\\ 
...
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following for the two lines of equation that are worked out (the ... are some other code, but not relevant to the question)[image]
As can be seen the first line is too long for the page and "pushes" the equation number to another line. Is there a way to shrink the equation, for example by using less space in the part before the integrals where the $1$'s are?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you should either rewrite the first line or break the line in two, directly shrinking it hurts readability and should always be avoided

Comment: (i) please correct your code snippet (packages had to be loaded before `begin{document}`, missing is document class); the most what can be done without breaking line is: `\begin{align}
    I &:= ...\\
      &=(1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^m(-1)^n)b_{mn}
        \int\limits_0^\infty\xi_2^n \int\limits_0^\infty\xi_1^m
        \mathrm{e}^{(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1\xi_1^2)}\mathrm{d}\xi_1 \mathrm{e}^{(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_2\xi_2^2)}\mathrm{d}\xi_2\\
      & = (1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^m(-1)^n)I_1
    \end{align}`

Comment: It is part of a page-long derivation, and splitting it over two lines makes the readability of the total more difficult, that's why I'm hesitating to do it. But if it's the only solution, it's the only solution.

Comment: I would define a new function $f(m,n)=1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^{m+n}$.

Comment: Using `(-1)^{m+n}` instead of `(-1)^m(-1)^n` would already be a good start. YOu might also consider using `e^{-\lambda_1\xi_1^2/2}` instead of `\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1\xi_1^2}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `flalign`, the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` and `geometry` to have a more decant right margin. Unrelated: I replaced `:=` with `\coloneqq` from `mathtools`, so the colon be centred on the math axis:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
 I&\coloneqq ... & & & & \\
    &=\medmath{(1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^m(-1)^n)b_{mn}\int_0^\infty\!\!\xi_2^n\int_0^\infty\!\!\xi_1^m\exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_1\xi_1^2\Bigr)\,\mathrm d\xi_1\exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_2\xi_2^2\Bigr)\,\mathrm d\xi_2}\\
    & = (1+(-1)^m+(-1)^n+(-1)^m(-1)^n)I_1\\
    ...
    \end{flalign}
    \end{document
```

} 
[image]